# Conversion of iterative algorithm to recursive

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, recursion, iteration

Hi I am trying to convert my iterative algorithm to recursive solution to achieve Dynamic Programming after it's done (Do suggest me other ways to reduce time complexity of this triple nested iteration). I am not good with recursion. I had tried to convert it but it is giving me index out of range errors.

Iterative Approach:

```
def foo(L):
          L=sorted(L)
          A = 0
          for i,x in enumerate(L):
            for j,y in enumerate(L):
                if x != y:
                    if (y%x ==0):
                        for k,z in enumerate(L):
                            if y != z:
                                if (z%y==0) and (y%x==0):
                                    A= A+1

          return A
```

Recursive Approach:

```
A =i =j= k =0 #Initializing globals
def foo(L):
              L=sorted(L)
              global A ,i,j,k
              x=y=z=L
              luckyOne(x,y,z)
              return A

def luckyOne(x,y,z):
    global i,j,k
    while(i< len(x) and j < len(y) and k < len(z)):
        while(x[i] != y[j]):
            luckyTwo(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
            i+=1 
            luckyOne(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
            # i+=1 
            # return A
        i+=1 
        luckyOne(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
    return 0

def luckyTwo(x,y,z):
    global i,j,k
    while (i< len(x) and j < len(y) and k < len(z)):
        while(y[j]%x[i]==0):
            luckyThree(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
            j+=1 
            luckyTwo(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
        j+=1 
        luckyTwo(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
    return 0

def luckyThree(x,y,z):
    global A ,i,j,k
    while (i< len(x) and j < len(y) and k < len(z)):
        while (y[j]!=z[k]):
            while((z[k]%y[j]==0) and (y[j]%x[i]==0)):
                A+=1
                print 'idr aya'
                k+=1 
                luckyThree(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
        k+=1 
        luckyThree(x[i:],y[j:],z[k:])
    return 0
```

The input should be like L=['1','2','3']

Comment: Why would you think that converting the algorithm to recursive version is going to reduce time complexity? The time complexity will probably be the same, and might even be worse, and recursion is *way more expensive* than a loop, so your constant factors will almost certainly be higher.

Comment: Because after achieving recursion i will try to add memoization to reduce time complexity. correct me if I am wrong. Also if you can suggest me other ways to reduce time complexity of this triple nested loop.

Comment: Note that the default recursion depth in python is only 1000...

Comment: First up, why are you calling `enumerate` when you never need the indices?

Comment: If L is only three items long, you don't need to make this faster.  You need to make it more readable, which probably means using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of nested loops.

Comment: @Kevin No,  The length of l is between 2 and 2000 inclusive.  The elements of l are between 1 and 999999 inclusive.

Comment: @user2357112 forgot to remove that after removing indices use.

Comment: 2000**3 = 8e9, which is a lot, but even with the high overhead of the Python interpreter, that's still O(minutes) in my estimation, given a multi-GHz processor.

Comment: But still can you suggest ways to further reduce the time to achieve result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the fastest version I can come up with:

```
def foo(lst):
    edges = {x: [y for y in lst if x != y and y % x == 0] for x in set(lst)}
    return sum(len(edges[y]) for x in lst for y in edges[x])
```

This should be significantly faster (1/7th the time in my test of lists with 100 elements).

The algorithm is essentially to build a directed graph where the nodes are the numbers in the list. Edges go from node A to node B iff the integer values of those nodes are different and A divides evenly into B.

Then traverse the graph. For each starting node A, find all the nodes B where there's an edge from A to B. On paper, we would then go to all the next nodes C, but we don't need to... we can just count how many edges are leaving node B and add that to our total.

**EDIT**

Depending on the distribution of values in the list, this is probably faster:

```
def foo(lst):
    counts = Counter(lst)
    edges = {x: [y for y in counts if x != y and y % x == 0] for x in counts}
    return sum(counts[x] * counts[y] * sum(counts[z] for z in edges[y]) for x in counts for y in edges[x])
```

Here, you can think of nodes as having a numeric value and a count. This avoids duplicate nodes for duplicate values in the input. Then we basically do the same thing but multiply by the appropriate count at each step.

**EDIT 2**

```
def foo(lst):
    counts = collections.Counter(lst)
    edges = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for x, y in itertools.combinations(sorted(counts), 2):
        if y % x == 0:
            edges[x].append(y)
    return sum(counts[x] * counts[y] * sum(counts[z] for z in edges[y]) for x in counts for y in edges[x])
```

Slight improvement thanks to @Blckknght. Sorting the unique values first saves some time in enumeration.

**EDIT 3**

See comments, but the original code in this question was actually wrong. Here's code that (I think) does the right thing based on the problem description which can be found in the comments:

```
def foo3(lst):
    count = 0

    for x, y, z in itertools.combinations(lst, 3):
        if y % x == 0 and z % y == 0:
            count += 1

    return count

print(foo3([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))  # 3
print(foo3([6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))  # 0
```

**EDIT 4**

*Much* faster version of the previous code:

```
def foo4(lst):
    edges = [[] for _ in range(len(lst))]

    for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(lst)), 2):
        if lst[j] % lst[i] == 0:
            edges[i].append(j)

    return sum(len(edges[j]) for i in range(len(lst)) for j in edges[i])
```

**EDIT 5**

More compact version (seems to run in about the same amount of time):

```
def foo5(lst):
    edges = [[j for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)) if lst[j] % lst[i] == 0] for i in range(len(lst))]
    return sum(len(edges[j]) for i in range(len(lst)) for j in edges[i])
```

Comment: B should also evenly divide C is this condition been catered here?

Comment: Yes. There's only an edge from B to C if B evenly divides into C.

Comment: foo(range(1,21)) == 40 for both

Comment: Yeah, I've tried many thousands of random lists (`[random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(100)]`), and I have yet to find one that doesn't produce the same output as the original code.

Comment: But it is failing some test cases I don't know why

Comment: Please share a test case where it's failing, and maybe we can figure it out.

Comment: I think there is some problem with my original algorithm because this is much faster and giving same results.

Comment: What my code is basically trying to achieve is the count of these kinds of triple tuples in list which are triple multiples. [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] has the triples: [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 6].

Comment: @MuhammadShehrozSajjad It sounds like the problem description comes from somewhere else... can you share (or link to) the full problem description?

Comment: I have to find number of tuples in a given list such that  a tuple (x, y, z) where x divides y and y divides z, such as (1, 2, 4).

Comment: If that's the entire problem description, it's hopelessly vague. It sounds like you have access to some test cases, one of which your code fails. Can you share the test cases?

Comment: Complete Description: Write a function answer(l) that takes a list of positive integers l and counts the number of "lucky triples" of (lst[i], lst[j], lst[k]) where i < j < k.  The length of l is between 2 and 2000 inclusive.  The elements of l are between 1 and 999999 inclusive. A "lucky triple" is a tuple (x, y, z) where x divides y and y divides z, such as (1, 2, 4).

Comment: I think I found the problem description: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144510/google-foobar-challenge-lucky-triples. If so, I think the issue is that you're excluding pairs that are equal. (Your `if x != y` and `if y != z` shouldn't be there.)

Comment: Oh, actually your problem description is different. Where did it come from?

Comment: This seems to match your description: https://gist.github.com/christophercrouzet/421fc9bdf646c93d099c109d6740cea1

Comment: So here the problem is that you can't sort the list because order matters, and a "triple" only counts if it has ascending IDs. Let me take a stab.

Comment: Take a look at my latest edit and see if that does what you want.

Comment: Er, one more ninja edit to "edit 3". We're back to something that's perhaps too slow... I'll try to optimize. I just want to make sure it's correct first.

Comment: [1,1,1]  should return 1 but it is giving 27 here.

Comment: I'm getting `1`. Maybe you grabbed the code before my ninja edit. :-)

Comment: Yes it is giving correct answer and the main mistake in my code was the condition x!=y and y!=z

Comment: See "EDIT 4" above. That's a much faster version.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd solve your problem. It should use `O(N**2)` time.

```
def count_triple_multiples(lst):
    count = collections.Counter(lst)
    double_count = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for x, y in itertools.combinations(sorted(count), 2):
        if y % x == 0:
            double_count[y] += count[x] * count[y]
    triple_count = 0
    for x, y in itertools.combinations(sorted(double_count), 2):
        if y % x == 0:
            triple_count += double_count[x] * count[y]
    return triple_count
```

My algorithm is very similar to the one smarx is using in his answer, but I keep a count of the number of edges incident to a given value rather than a list.

Comment: Nice! This appears to be a bit faster than my solution.

Comment: See the latest edit to my solution; it now seems to be slightly faster than yours.

Comment: Yeah, I figured some combination of our two ideas might be optimal, but I couldn't see quite how to get there. It looks like you may have found it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as speeding things up goes (instead of going recursive), testing with 1000 entries, slicing the sorted list at each level cut time by more than half for me (gets rid of numbers less than `y, z` at their respective levels:

```
def foo(L):
    assert 0 not in L
    L=sorted(L)
    A = 0
    for i,x in enumerate(L):
        for j,y in enumerate(L[i + 1:]):
            if x != y and not y % x:
                for k,z in enumerate(L[i + j + 2:]):
                    if y != z and not z % y:
                        A = A + 1

    return A
```

Comment: It is faster but not fast enough.

Comment: Also shouldn't you just write L[i + 1:][j + 1:] as L[j+1:]?

Comment: @MuhammadShehrozSajjad `j` is relative to the sliced list, not the original list.  But I just realized you can save on a slice by doing `L[i + j + 2:]` instead.

Comment: Still the other solutions given here are way faster than this on a larger input.